# ARM Templates are still the preferred deployment mechanism?

Tags: azure-resource-manager

We're a little aghast at how time consuming it is to develop syntactically correct ARM templates from scratch.

The Portal helps, but pushes out non-development ready templates (pretty hard to find what the bug is when all the templates use 'name' for the resource name, versus maybe something more verbose like ('microsoftStorageAccountResourceName', microsoftStorageAccountResourceLocation, microsoftStorageAccountResourceTags, etc.).

We understand that there are many ways to deploy -- but if at all possible, we'd like some assurances that ARM is the current preferred way *and* will continue to be the preferred primary means of scripting deployments via VSTS -- or is it sliding towards a different -- maybe more programmatic -- approach (eg: Powershell, CLI, other).

We're asking this because it looks like we will have to invest significant effort to create a resource library for this organisation (to decrease the need for all projects to become proficient at ARM deployment) -- and would prefer to do it using an approach that will be preferred by developers over the coming years, for maintainability objectives.

Thanks for any insight on which approach to recommend as the best investment.

Comment: You have several options cli powershell ARM template. I think it is up to you to decide what is suitable for your organization. You can create logic app or even azure automation runbook to deploy smaller arm template or script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Templates are going to be around for the foreseeable future... it really depends on whether you want to orchestrate the deployment yourself (imperative deployments using CLI, PS, SDK) or you want ARM to orchestrate the deployment (via templates).  Happy to chat in offline if you want to discuss more - email bmoore at microsoft.

Comment: Thank you. Having orchestration taken care of is worth the effort required to develop templates in a hybrid JSON/Javascriptish files. 
But will remain convinced that MS should look into whether a less verbose, YAML-ish, template language would make it less costly to develop. Kind regards.

Comment: I'd be interested in talking more with you about that - if you're interested, email me - bmoore at microsoft

Answer (score 0):

Writing this now one year after the original post: The answer to 'ARM Templates are still the preferred deployment mechanism?' probably depends on who you ask. "Preferred" by Microsoft according to their product strategy may be meant differently than preferred by actual users that, well, feel the pain of vendor strategy decisions. I had started with an Azure automation book that used PS scripting only; I was lead (maybe mis-lead?) then to the ARM Template deployment model, mainly by the Microsoft web documentations, but found out that those templates need so much rework that writing a PS script, or even writing an ARM Template from scratch, seems to be a more efficient way to go. In fact, I am confused at the moment about what the 'Best Practice' is, i.e. what method other developers actually use. Is there a community-established opinion on this matter, now in August 2019? Or is it all VSTS / 3rd-party IDEs nowadays?